# What is the Java equivalent for C# `Interlocked.Exchange(Object, Object) : Object`?

Tags: java, c#, locking, interlocked

What is the Java equivalent for C# `Interlocked.Exchange(Object, Object) : Object`? Is there a way in Java to perform the following actions in a single atomic step *without lock*: 1) store locally the reference of a variable 2) set another reference to the same variable?

Comment: You assume `Interlocked` doesn't use a lock. Any source for that?

Comment: It doesn't. I will let @jon-skeet answer your question ;-) [Here](http://www.albahari.com/threading/part4.aspx#_Interlocked) you find an detailed explanation.

Comment: Okay. I read from your question you thought it did.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There's no operation to do this for an arbitrary variable, as far as I'm aware... but this is what the [`AtomicReference`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicReference.html) type is for:

```
private AtomicReference<String> stringReference;

...

String oldValue = stringReference.getAndSet(newValue);
```